# Where to Store all my scene name in one place

Tags: unity-game-engine, structure

I am making a probject in Unity, and would like to have one play to access all my SceneNaming;

Right now in the UI, I have to set the scene name manually.

[image]

I would like to store all my scene name in an object, so that I can just use a drag drop to choose all my scenes names.

I tried to put a static class and have then like this

```
 public static string SCENE_MENU = "Menu";
 public static string SCENE_WORLD = "Demo";
```

or inside an enum

```
 public enum SCENE_NAME{
 Menu, Demo
 }
```

and then use GetName on the enum to get the value

What is the best approach? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaXnW.png): /storage/temp/135402-screenshot-1.png

Comment: [Scriptable objects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) might be another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a customer editor script you could use a [`SceneAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) to store a Scene's path instead.

*I will use a CustomEditor here since for starters it's easier to understand what happens there. Later you might want to switch it to a `CustomPropertyDrawer` wot a proper class or maybe even as Attribute.*

Place this in anywhere in the `Assets`

```c#
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ScenePath;

    public void Load()
    {
        //e.g.
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(ScenePath);
    }
}
```

Place this inside of a folder `Editor` (so it will not be included in a build where the `UnityEditor` namespace does not exist)

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(SceneLoader), true)]
public class ScenePickerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _scenePath;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _scenePath = serializezObject.FindProperty("ScenePath");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Draw the usual script field
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
         EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(.FromMonoBehaviour((SceneLoader)target), typeof(SceneLoader), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        // Loads current Values into the serialized "copy"
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Get the current scene asset for the current path
        var currentScene = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_scenePath.stringValue) ? AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<SceneAsset>(_scenePath.stringValue) : null;          

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        var newScene = (SceneAsset)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Scene", currentScene, typeof(SceneAsset), false);

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            _scenePath.stringValue = newScene != Null ? AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(newScene) : "";               
        }

        // Write back changes to the actual component
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

And e.g. to your button attach that SceneLoader component.

Than you can simply reference the target scene in the Inspector via drag and drop. Internally it instead stores the according ScenePath.

Now in `onClick` instead use that `SceneLoader.Load`.

---

**Note:**
As mentioned [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-link-scenes-in-the-inspector.383140/) only storing the scene path might not be "save" and breaks if you later move the according scene or rename it. So maybe it would be a good extension to also store according object reference as a kind of fallback.

---

You could than also use this approach and extend it to be a central manager instead like

```c#
// It could as well be a ScriptableObject object

// this makes e.g. Awake run already in edit mode
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class ScenePathManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I would prefere references but for ease of this post
    // use a Singleton for access
    public static ScenePathManager Instance;

    public List<string> AvailableScenePaths = new List<string>();

    private void Awake ()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

and in the editor script use a list (again there are more beautiful ways like `ReorderableList` bit this would get to complex here

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(ScenePathManager))]
public class ScenePathManagerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _availablePaths;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        _availablePaths = serializedObject.FindProperty("AvailablScenePaths");
    }

    public override OnInpectorGUI ()
    {
        // Draw the usual script field
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(.FromMonoBehaviour((SceneLoader)target), typeof(SceneLoader), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        serializedObject.Update();

        //Do the same thing as before but this time in a loop
        for(var i=0; i<_availablePaths.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var _scenePath = _availablePaths.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

             // Loads current Values into the serialized "copy"
            serializedObject.Update();

            // Get the current scene asset for the current path
            var currentScene = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_scenePath.stringValue) ? AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<SceneAsset>(_scenePath.stringValue) : null;          

            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            var newScene = (SceneAsset)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Scene", currentScene, typeof(SceneAsset), false);

            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
            {
                _scenePath.stringValue = newScene != Null ? AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(newScene) : "";               
            }
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Than you could reference all needed scenes in that manager and than on your `SceneLoader` instead have a `Popup` field (like for enums) in order to select the scene you want

```c#
[CustomEditor (typeof (SceneLoader))]
public class SceneLoaderEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _scenePath;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        _scenePath = serializedObject.FindProperty("ScenePath");
    }

    public override void OnInpectorGUI ()
    {
        //Let me shorten it a bit this time ^^

        serializedObject.Update();
        var availablePaths = ScenePathManager.Instance ? ScenePathManager.Instance.AvailableScenePaths : new List<string>();

        var currentIndex = availablePaths.FirstOrDefault(path => string.Equals(path, _scenePath.stringValue)));

        var newIndex = EditorGUILayout.PopupField("Scene", currentIndex, availabePaths.ToArray());

        _scenePath.stringValue = availablePaths[newIndex];

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

This should than give you a selection dropdown for the scene.

**Note** this might, however, without the object reference as backing field break evem faster of any of those strings or indexes change...

**But** you could use this with your manager also without the whole `SceneAsset` approach but only for simple strings.

---

*Typed on my smartphone so no warranty but I hope I make my point clear*

Comment: I updated to also include a way for getting the drop-down field you mentioned .. even without the Scene asset way you could still use it for the scene names instead as your original attempt was.

Comment: Where do you populate AvailableScenePaths ? I tried to do this inside ScenePAthManager but the Awake is never called

Comment: with `[ExecuteInEditoMode]` the `Awake` in the Editor is only called on re-compilation of scripts or loading of the Scene. You can simply edit the List in the Inspector (set the `Size` to whatever size you want and start referencing Scenes/entering strings). Unfortunately I'm not with my PC now but later maybe I could add some screenshots (and actually test it ;) )

Comment: dont worry I will find out thanks for all the help !